# Text and background of the tabs are white when the site is in read-only in mobile

Tags: bug, mobile-web

The text and background of the current selected tab are white in mobile web version, when the site is in read-only mode. It's very hard to read it, can you please fix it?

[image: a screenshot]

I noticed this in Chrome on Android when the sites were in read-only mode on Nov 1.

Comment: Browser and OS?